# How can I find the number of years between two dates?

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to determine an age in years from a certain date.  Does anyone know a clean way to do this in Android?  I have the Java api available obviously, but the straight-up java api is pretty weak, and I was hoping that Android has something to help me out.

EDIT: The multiple recommendations to use Joda time in Android worries me a bit due to [Android Java - Joda Date is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059663/android-java-joda-date-is-slow) and related concerns.  Also, pulling in a library not shipped with the platform for something this size is probably overkill.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java

Comment: Both the legacy `Date`/`Calendar` classes and *Joda-Time* have been supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
import java.util.Date;

public static int getDiffYears(Date first, Date last) {
    Calendar a = getCalendar(first);
    Calendar b = getCalendar(last);
    int diff = b.get(YEAR) - a.get(YEAR);
    if (a.get(MONTH) > b.get(MONTH) || 
        (a.get(MONTH) == b.get(MONTH) && a.get(DATE) > b.get(DATE))) {
        diff--;
    }
    return diff;
}

public static Calendar getCalendar(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

**Note**: as [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) noticed, this won't work with dates before Christ due how Calendar works.

Comment: What are the constants MONTH, YEAR and DATE ??

Comment: @ChrisSim: They are static imports of Calendar.MONTH and so on.

Comment: I think instead of DATE it should be DAY_OF_MONTH.

Comment: @jiahao: they're synonyms

Comment: .get(YEAR) and .get(MONTH) are now deprecated I believe. Possibly edit?

Comment: @Iridann: where do you see that? There's nothing deprecated: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @sinuhepop My bad, that's Calendar.getYear() I read as being deprecated!

Comment: @sinuhepop Although saying that I thought that the convention was to use the form Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Keep in mind to add +1 to Calendar.MONTH if comparing Calendar.getInstance() with your set date!

Comment: int diff = b.get(Calendar.YEAR) - a.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                if (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) > b.get(Calendar.MONTH) ||
                        (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) == b.get(Calendar.MONTH) && a.get(Calendar.DATE) > b.get(Calendar.DATE))) {
                    diff--;
                }

Comment: How long did Roman emperor Augustus live? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_emperors#27_BC%E2%80%9368_AD:_Julio-Claudian_dynasty) 75 years. Feeding the dates from there into your code gave: -50 (minus fifty).

Comment: @OleV.V.: Good find! I'll update my answer.

Comment: `if (a.get(MONTH) > b.get(MONTH) || 
        (a.get(MONTH) == b.get(MONTH) && a.get(DATE) > b.get(DATE))) {
        diff--;
    }`
why did you use this condition?

Comment: @mr.sanatbek: it tells if **a** is after **b** (excluding years)

Comment: if (a.get(MONTH) < b.get(MONTH) || 
        (a.get(MONTH) == b.get(MONTH) && a.get(DATE) < b.get(DATE))) {
        diff++;  // for comparison purpose
    }

Comment: use import static java.util.Calendar.*; in your code.

Comment: @ShivBuyya: Third line in my code is exactly that.

Answer (score 51):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( 
    LocalDate.of( 2010 , 1 , 1 ) , 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
)
```

Test for zero years elapsed, and one year elapsed.

```java
ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( 
    LocalDate.of( 2010 , 1 , 1 )  , 
    LocalDate.of( 2010 , 6 , 1 ) 
)
```

> 0

```java
ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( 
    LocalDate.of( 2010 , 1 , 1 )  , 
    LocalDate.of( 2011 , 1 , 1 ) 
)
```

> 1

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3aVjsg).

## java.time

The old date-time classes really are bad, so bad that both Sun & Oracle agreed to supplant them with the java.time classes. If you do any significant work at all with date-time values, adding a library to your project is worthwhile. The Joda-Time library was highly successful and recommended, but is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2010 , 1 , 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
long years = java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( start , stop );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "start: " + start + " | stop: " + stop + " | years: " + years ) ;
```

> start: 2010-01-01 | stop: 2016-09-06 | years: 6

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: This does the diff of actual year number only but not the calculated year based on actual full date.

Comment: @SmartCoder I do not understand your Comment. I read the Question as asking for age, number of years reached on an anniversary date. The code shown does so. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/3aVjsg) on Ideone.com.

Comment: I used the code to calculate year based on actual date and it just gives the difference of year number. It'd actually calculate based on date difference. The date '09/12/2022' an '11/23/2020' should give diff of just one year and not two.

Comment: @SmartCoder Indeed, yes. `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( LocalDate.of( 2020 , 11 , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2022 , 9 , 12 ) )` returns `1`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/3aVjsg).

Comment: @SmartCoder If I have missed your point, please explain. I do not see how you got a result of two years when comparing those two dates.

Answer (score 19):

I would recommend using the great [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for everything date related in Java.

For your needs you can use the [`Years.yearsBetween()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Years.html#yearsBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) method.

Comment: I've used Joda a lot this last project. It is really over kill in terms of setting up...

Comment: Just to elaborate:
`public int getYears(org.java.util.Date time) {
org.joda.time.DateTime now = org.joda.time.DateTime.now();
org.joda.time.DateTime then = new org.joda.time.DateTime(time.getTime());
return org.joda.time.Years.yearsBetween(now, then).getYears();
}`

Comment: An update, a decade later… The *Joda-Time* framework has been supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8+, defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). *Joda-Time* is now in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Both *Joda-Time* and *java.time* are led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

Answer (score 5):

I apparently can't comment yet, but I think you can just use the DAY_OF_YEAR to workout if you should adjust the years down one (copied and modified from current best answer)

```
public static int getDiffYears(Date first, Date last) {
    Calendar a = getCalendar(first);
    Calendar b = getCalendar(last);
    int diff = b.get(Calendar.YEAR) - a.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (a.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > b.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
        diff--;
    }
    return diff;
}

public static Calendar getCalendar(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

Similarly you could probably just diff the ms representations of the time and divide by the number of ms in a year.  Just keep everything in longs and that should be good enough most of the time (leap years, ouch) but it depends on your application for the number of years and how performant that function has to be weather it would be worth that kind of hack.

Comment: Using DAY_OF_YEAR leads to errors with leap years too.

Comment: if (a.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < b.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
        diff++;
    }

Answer (score 1):

I know you have asked for a clean solution, but here are two dirty once:

```
        static void diffYears1()
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // now
    String toDate = dateFormat.format(calendar1.getTime());

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7000); // some date in the past
    String fromDate = dateFormat.format(calendar2.getTime());

    // just simply add one year at a time to the earlier date until it becomes later then the other one 
    int years = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        calendar2.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        if(calendar2.getTimeInMillis() < calendar1.getTimeInMillis())
            years++;
        else
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(years + " years between " + fromDate + " and " + toDate);
}

static void diffYears2()
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // now
    String toDate = dateFormat.format(calendar1.getTime());

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7000); // some date in the past
    String fromDate = dateFormat.format(calendar2.getTime());

    // first get the years difference from the dates themselves
    int years = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    // now make the earlier date the same year as the later
    calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    // and see if new date become later, if so then one year was not whole, so subtract 1 
    if(calendar2.getTimeInMillis() > calendar1.getTimeInMillis())
        years--;

    System.out.println(years + " years between " + fromDate + " and " + toDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is a better method:

```
public int getYearsBetweenDates(Date first, Date second) {
    Calendar firstCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    Calendar secondCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    firstCal.setTime(first);
    secondCal.setTime(second);

    secondCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1 - firstCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

    return secondCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - firstCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

**EDIT**

Apart from a bug which I fixed, this method does not work well with leap years. Here's a complete test suite. I guess you're better off using the accepted answer.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class YearsBetweenDates {
    public static int getYearsBetweenDates(Date first, Date second) {
        Calendar firstCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        Calendar secondCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

        firstCal.setTime(first);
        secondCal.setTime(second);

        secondCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1 - firstCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

        return secondCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - firstCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    private static class TestCase {
        public Calendar date1;
        public Calendar date2;
        public int expectedYearDiff;
        public String comment;

        public TestCase(Calendar date1, Calendar date2, int expectedYearDiff, String comment) {
            this.date1 = date1;
            this.date2 = date2;
            this.expectedYearDiff = expectedYearDiff;
            this.comment = comment;
        }
    }

    private static TestCase[] tests = {
        new TestCase(
                new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.JULY, 15),
                new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.JULY, 15),
                1,
                "exactly one year"),
        new TestCase(
                new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.JULY, 15),
                new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.JULY, 14),
                2,
                "one day less than 3 years"),
        new TestCase(
                new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 3),
                new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.MAY, 3),
                1,
                "a year and a half"),
        new TestCase(
                new GregorianCalendar(2016, Calendar.JULY, 15),
                new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.JULY, 15),
                1,
                "leap years do not compare correctly"),
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        for (TestCase t : tests) {
            int diff = getYearsBetweenDates(t.date1.getTime(), t.date2.getTime());
            String result = diff == t.expectedYearDiff ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
            System.out.println(t.comment + ": " +
                    df.format(t.date1.getTime()) + " -> " +
                    df.format(t.date2.getTime()) + " = " +
                    diff + ": " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There was a bug related to days being one-based. But this also doesn't work well with leap years. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

a handy one if you don't want to border Calendar, Locale, or external library:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat YYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
public static Integer toDate8d(Date date) {
    String s;
    synchronized (YYYYMMDD) { s = YYYYMMDD.format(date); }  // SimpleDateFormat thread safety
    return Integer.valueOf(s);
}
public static Integer yearDiff(Date pEarlier, Date pLater) {
    return (toDate8d(pLater) - toDate8d(pEarlier)) / 10000;
}
```

Comment: Any advantage over the one-liner by Basil Bourque? I recommend staying away form `SImpleDateFormat`, it’s a notorious troublemaker of a class. And converting to an `int` the numerical value if which makes no sense? Me don’t like.

Comment: comparing to Basil's is mainly the learning curve of java.time cos not everyone would have much time to spend on studying;   SimpleDateFormat is only by design to be minimal and not for multithreading so many people may hit issues if they are not aware.  This can be easily resolved by a simple synchironized block;  this int solution move the logic computation from partially-library to simple maths computation wich is in fact not complex.  This is of least use of library it don't even need to involve Calendar class;  this is intuitive and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to calculate it using java's Calendar you can use [Androids Time class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)  It is supposed to be faster but I didn't notice much difference when i switched.

I could not find any pre-defined functions to determine time between 2 dates for an age in Android.  There are some nice helper functions to get formatted time between dates in the [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
// int year =2000;  int month =9 ;    int day=30;

    public int getAge (int year, int month, int day) {

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            int y, m, d, noofyears;         

            y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);// current year ,
            m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);// current month 
            d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);//current day
            cal.set(year, month, day);// here ur date 
            noofyears = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                            || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (d < cal
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
                    --noofyears;
            }
            if(noofyears < 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("age < 0");
             System.out.println(noofyears);
            return noofyears;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work and if you want the number of years replace 12 to 1

```
    String date1 = "07-01-2015";
    String date2 = "07-11-2015";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(date1.substring(6));
    int j = Integer.parseInt(date2.substring(6));
    int p = Integer.parseInt(date1.substring(3,5));
    int q = Integer.parseInt(date2.substring(3,5));


    int z;
    if(q>=p){
        z=q-p + (j-i)*12;
    }else{
        z=p-q + (j-i)*12;
    }
    System.out.println("The Total Months difference between two dates is --> "+z+" Months");
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I tried your code with `date1 = "07-11-2015"`and `date2 = "07-01-2016"`. Expected result was 2 months, Instead I got `The Total Months difference between two dates is --> 22 Months`. It’s easier than you think to get date math wrong, and even more so when you choose poor variable names. There is a reason why people prefer and advocate the library classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ole V.v for reviewing it: i have found some inbuilt library classes which does the same

```
    int noOfMonths = 0;
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(startDate);

    DateTime endDate11 = new DateTime();
    Months m = Months.monthsBetween(dt, endDate11);
    noOfMonths = m.getMonths();
    System.out.println(noOfMonths);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int getYear(Date date1,Date date2){ 
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
      Integer.parseInt(simpleDateformat.format(date1));

      return Integer.parseInt(simpleDateformat.format(date2))- Integer.parseInt(simpleDateformat.format(date1));

    }
```

Comment: @Johnny Graber care to explain why you  upvoted this ... ehem ... suboptimal answer?

Comment: Downvoted as this does not take the days into account.