# Get day, year and month for itself

Tags: java, android

Now it's like this, I have a `long` variable with date and time on it. So I use DateFormat to get the date and time for itself, and now I want to get the year, month, day, hour and minutes for itself. The date and time is in a `String`, so actually I could just cut the string with `substring` and all that. But since like for example Sweden has their date like this: "dd/mm/yyyy", and the US has their date like this: "mm/dd/yyyy". So if I just cut the String for the Swedish date, the day variable will become the month.

This is my code:

```
String start = mCursor.getLong(1);

Format df = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this);
Format tf = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this);

String date = df.format(start);
String time = tf.format(start);
```

So my question is, is there someway to get the year, month, day, hour and minute for itself in a own String?

Thanks in advance, GuiceU. (Bad english, I know)

Comment: You could use `jodatime`, but check for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059663/android-java-joda-date-is-slow

Comment: In Java you can use `GregorianCalendar`, or `JodaTime`. I do not know if it has been ported to android, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way.   Use `java.util.Calendar`:

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
String dateStr = "2012-Dec-21";
Date date = dateFormatter.parse(dateStr);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: Yeaaah, it works! But since I get my date from an Cursor, and have to first format it to a String with df.format(); Then it returns a String like this: "2012-12-21", and with your method it needs to be like this: "2012-Dec-21". But maybe I can change that in someway?

Comment: Naaah, sorry! My bad! Did'nt notice the 'yyyy-MMM-dd' in the 
'DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");'

So thanks dude!

Comment: Merry Christmas.  Accept the answer if it helped - good for you, good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like both the question and accepted answer ignore time zone, which is probably a problem.

This work is much easier with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time.* package in Java 8. You said you have `long` primitive value, so let's start there assuming it represents milliseconds from Unix epoch (1970). No need to deal with creating or parsing string representations of the date at all. Joda-Time offers many points of access to year, month, etc. numbers and names. And Joda-Time localizes the names to Swedish or English.

The date style code is a pair of characters. The first character is the date style, and the second character is the time style. Specify a character of 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full. A date or time may be omitted by specifying a style character '-'.

```
long input = DateTime.now().getMillis();

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Stockholm" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );
int year = dateTime.getYear();
int month = dateTime.getMonthOfYear(); // 1-based counting, 1 = January. Unlike crazy java.util.Date/Calendar.
int dayOfMonth = dateTime.getDayOfMonth();
int hourOfDay = dateTime.getHourOfDay();
int minuteOfHour = dateTime.getMinuteOfHour();

java.util.Locale localeSweden = new Locale( "sv", "SE" ); // ( language code, country code );
String monthName_Swedish = dateTime.monthOfYear().getAsText( localeSweden );
String monthName_UnitedStates = dateTime.monthOfYear().getAsText( java.util.Locale.US );

DateTimeFormatter formatter_Sweden = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "LM" ).withLocale( localeSweden ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTimeFormatter formatter_UnitedStates_NewYork = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "LM" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.US ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" ) );
String text_Swedish = formatter_Sweden.print( dateTime );
String text_UnitedStates_NewYork = formatter_UnitedStates_NewYork.print( dateTime );

DateTime dateTimeUtcGmt = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "monthName_Swedish: " + monthName_Swedish );
System.out.println( "monthName_UnitedStates: " + monthName_UnitedStates );
System.out.println( "text_Swedish: " + text_Swedish );
System.out.println( "text_UnitedStates_NewYork: " + text_UnitedStates_NewYork );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtcGmt: " + dateTimeUtcGmt );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-02-16T07:12:19.301+01:00
monthName_Swedish: februari
monthName_UnitedStates: February
text_Swedish: den 16 februari 2014 07:12:19
text_UnitedStates_NewYork: February 16, 2014 1:12:19 AM
dateTimeUtcGmt: 2014-02-16T06:12:19.301Z
```