# joda time consume too much memory

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I use joda time in my code.  When I add this line of code, the using memory will be increased 30M!

```
LocalDateTime _currDate = new LocalDateTime();
```

I found that nearly all the java programmers recommend to use joda time.  so I think maybe I didn't use it in a right way.  Anyone knows the reason, please help me.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking at the memory that the JVM uses within the operating system, or the memory usage within the JVM? In other words: are you looking at `top` or Task Manager, or are you looking at VisualVM?

Comment: @Barend I use Task Manager to monitor the memory usage.  The weird thing is: when I add this line of code, my app crash.  I found the reason of crash is the memory usage reached to the limit level.  When I comment this line of code, my app works well.  And I found the memory usage decreased by 30M in the task manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason of memory consuming for joda time.  This is the answer: [Android Java - Joda Date is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059663/android-java-joda-date-is-slow)
according plowman's solution, I solved this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The JVM is pretty sophisticated and just because you instantiate a new object doesn't mean it will consume memory at that line of code.  In some cases the JVM will never allocate memory to un-used objects EVEN if you explicitly instantiate them.  **You'll want to use a memory profiler to see what is exactly going on.**  Joda is a well built library and it's highly unlikely that this one class instantiation is causing your memory to increase by 30m.

A good profiler will show you how much memory that class is consuming, what's going on in the heap, along with several other useful insights.  **It could just be the JVM making more room on the heap to account for other things happening in your code.**

I'm sure others will chime in on some good profilers but some IDE's will have them built right in.  Start there and good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I use Task Manager to monitor the memory usage. The weird thing is: when I add this line of code, my app crash. I found the reason of crash is the memory usage reached to the limit level. When I comment this line of code, my app works well. And I found the memory usage decreased by 30M in the task manager.  Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: The Task Manager is not a good indicator.  Use a memory profiler.  As for the app crashing you'll need to post the error as it may be un-related to a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

[java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) supplants [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) , with a [back-port to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

You may see a different memory usage profile with this library, though I have not tested it.